# Errors in Deliver and Broadcast Service

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, grpc

I have created successfully a multi-org, multi-vm native (without docker) setup.

```
1VM = Peer1Org1

2VM = Peer1Org2

3VM = OrdererOrdererOrg
```

I successfully create, join the channel and install, instantiate, invoke and query an example chaincode, from both vms and all results are the same, query and invoke works fine. However, in orderer logs an error about deliver and broadcast appears.

> - 2019-02-21 17:52:00.022 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 01a Error reading from 192.168.50.30:34506: rpc error: code = Canceled
>     desc = context canceled
> - 2019-02-21 18:21:17.899 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 01c Error reading from 192.168.50.30:45054: rpc error: code =
>     Canceled desc = context canceled.

What are these errors? And why am I getting an error even the deliver and broadcast services are seem to work (because I get the correct results)?

Peers logs have no errors. I made the certificates using Fabric CA but without TLS.

Comment: Try setting the orderer logs to debug, e.g. `ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug`

Comment: 2019-02-27 15:12:41.954 UTC [grpc] warningf -> DEBU 72b transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to read frame: read tcp 192.168.50.41:7050->192.168.50.40:56960: read: connection reset by peer
2019-02-27 15:12:41.954 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 72c Error reading from 192.168.50.40:56960: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-02-27 15:12:41.954 UTC [orderer/common/server] func1 -> DEBU 72d Closing Broadcast stream
2019-02-27 15:12:41.954 UTC [grpc] infof -> DEBU 72e transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"

Comment: Deliver error is fixed, propably because i run CLI commands without evaluated privilages(sudo). 
But broadcast error is still here. The above errors is the output when i set loglevel=debug